# python pivot and average a dirty dateframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have homicide statistic 2003-2008 as csv file in python.

The problem is there is more rate values for the same year from different sources. 
For example homicide rate in US in 2004 is from 3 different sources. (3 values for the same year)

1-I would like to calculate the average of Rate per year for every country. Then I have a single rate for every country in every year.

2-Then I want to pivot rate per year to new columns. (column name: 2013 - value in row 12354 as rate)

*What matters to me is that the index should be number not country names. (0,1,...)

```
columns = ['country','rate','year','source']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df.loc[0] = ['US',25.0,2003,'international']
df.loc[1] = ['US',30,2003,'goverment']
df.loc[2] = ['US',35,2005,'goverment']
df.loc[3] = ['China',12.0,2004,'goverment']
df.loc[4] = ['China',15.0,2004,'international']


df.head()
    country rate    year    source
0   US     25.0     2003    international
1   US     30.0     2003    goverment
2   US     35.0     2005    goverment
3   China   12.0    2004    goverment
4   China   15.0    2004    international
```

Expected answer1:

```
   country  rate    year    
0   US     27.5     2003    
1   US     35.0     2005       
2   China   13.5    2004
```

Expected answer2:

```
   country  2003  2004   2005   
0   US      27.5         35 
1   China          13.5
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas dataframe: Group by two columns and then average over another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35587459/pandas-dataframe-group-by-two-columns-and-then-average-over-another-column).  Use the `groupby` parameter `as_index=False`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Using [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'country': ['US', 'US', 'US', 'China', 'China'],
        'rate': [25.2, 30.0, 35.0, 12.5, 15.6],
        'source': ['international', 'goverment', 'goverment', 'goverment', 'international'],
        'year': [2003, 2003, 2005, 2004, 2004]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# groupby
df_mean = df.groupby(['country', 'year'], as_index=False).mean()

  country  year   rate
0   China  2004  14.05
1      US  2003  27.60
2      US  2005  35.00

# pivot
df_pivot = df_mean.pivot(index='country', columns='year', values='rate').reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)

  country  2003   2004  2005
0   China   NaN  14.05   NaN
1      US  27.6    NaN  35.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a example

```
import pandas as pd

columns = ['country','rate','year','source']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
df.loc[0] = ['US',25.2,2003,'international']
df.loc[1] = ['US',30,2003,'goverment']
df.loc[2] = ['US',35,2005,'goverment']
df.loc[3] = ['China',12.5,2004,'goverment']
df.loc[4] = ['China',15.6,2004,'international']

df1=df.groupby(['country', 'year'], as_index=False)['rate'].mean()
print(df1)
# You can add .reset_index() for remove levels . For the NaN values just add .fillna('') in the final
df2 = df1.pivot_table(index=['country'], columns='year', values='rate')
print(df2)
```

Result :

```
  country  year   rate
0   China  2004  14.05
1      US  2003  27.60
2      US  2005  35.00

year     2003   2004  2005
country                   
China     NaN  14.05   NaN
US       27.6    NaN  35.0
```